# How to have Powerapps automatically generate existing Excel dropdowns?

Tags: excel, database, drop-down-menu, powerapps

I'm using MS Powerapps to create an app that uses an Excel as a datasource.

I've let PowerApps automatically generate the app and all the data's there. The problem is that the dropdown features are lost for each data point in the data set.

You can now fill out a random string... but that's not what I want. I want the user to be able to choose from a limited set of choices (e.g. 1,2,3,4).

How can I have Powerapps generate such an app?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

JP

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the values that are going to appear in dropdowns in a separate excel sheet, prefreably a separate spreadsheet for each dropdown.. See the images below

[image: Excel data]
[image: Excel tables]

And then you are going to add those tables as datasources to  your existing powerapp data connections.

Then, you will delete the textbozes and insert dropdowns onto your Edit form. 
Select that dropdown field and we're gonna go up to the top here to our Formula. We're gonna get rid of DropDownSample and we wanna connect it to the table that we want it to pull that data from. So  we will go back and take a look at our data sources, and write the name of the table we want to connect to there.

Hope this helps.